# Shapes get repeated in kineticjs stage.draw()?

Tags: kineticjs

When ever I draw shape, I just call stage.draw() method, 
so the shapes are repeated once again.
    So My question is how to add shapes without more occurrence of previously drawn shapes.
        Here sample code

```
//creating group for adding text
     var textGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
                    x: e.pageX,
                    y: e.pageY - posY,
                    draggable: true,
                    id: 'textgroup'
                });
                layer.add(textGroup);
                stage.add(layer);
                textname = 'text' + shapecount;
//creating text 
                var text = new Kinetic.Text({
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    text: comment,
                    fill: "#" + fillcolor,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    name: textname
                });
//adding text into group
                textGroup.add(text);
//finally drawing stage
                  stage.draw();


 Can anyone help me out?

    Thanks in Advance,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just call the draw() method on the group to which you added the shape. This will only redraw the shapes in that specific group. I.e. `textGroup.draw()`

In fact you can call the draw() method from any Node (including, Shapes, Layers, Stages, Groups etc).

**Update**

I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u9xHe/1/. Adding a Text shape, calling draw, then adding another Text shape and calling draw again. Nothing seems out of place in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Still i got same problem

Comment: Could you then clarify your problem a bit better. Maybe using a Fiddle example. The draw() method shouldn't add any more occurrences of a shape, but just redraw existing shapes.

Comment: I am drawing one rectangle and then drawing one circle 
in this case rectangle and circle were added only once.
when I save stage into  server and load again like the below method, 
 stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'toImage');
 
 here I got two occurrence of each shape

Comment: Then your problem is probably when you save the stage to the server, or when you create the stage from the JSON file. Could you provide the functionality for this part together with the JSON file? Also, if you don't want a shape to be drawn again, you can call shape.destroy(). Next time you call draw on one of its parents, the shape will not be drawn again.